# How to extract strings from Python tuples or lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop, tuples

I don't get why it doesn't work but I'm new to programming so I might be making some simple mistakes.

```
def tuplasemstr(t):
    tup1 = []
    n = 0
    while n <= 2 and type(t[n],) != str:
        list.append(tup1, t[n])
        n = n + 1

    return tuple(tup1)
```

I expected something like:

```
t = ("a",3,2.1)
```

Output:

```
(3,2.1)
```

Comment: As an aside, you really shouldn't use a while-loop here. Note, `while n <= 2 and type(t[n],) != str:` will terminate the first time you encounter something that is a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution given by @blhsing is the best one. But if you want to get your code working, you can do this:

```
def tuplasemstr(t):
    tup1 = []
    n = 0
    while n < len(t):
        if not isinstance(t[n], str):
            list.append(tup1, t[n])
        n = n + 1
    return tuple(tup1)

t = ('a', 3, 2.1, 'c', 32)
print(tuplasemstr(t)) # (3, 2.1, 32)
```

To check for strings you should use `isinstance` inside the while loop. Also, don't hardcode the length with `n <= 2`, use `n < len(t)` instead.

Comment: The reason your function doesn't behave the way you expect is because you check for the type at the same time as you enter the while loop. In your particular case, you get an empty tuple because your `while` loop is never executed. Doing it the way [@David Robles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179057/david-robles) shows you mean you will add any number of items that does *not* match a type of *str*, which is indeed better than hard-coding a number as it will work for any number of items in your tuple.

Comment: Thanks! The length '2' was actually a limitation given by the exercise.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to filter out string items in the tuple, you can use a generator expression with a condition that tests if the item is not an instance of string:

```
def tuplasemstr(t):
    return tuple(i for i in t if not isinstance(i, str))
```